# Why can not find all items by relationship field?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I start with sql statement. I have that sql (look below) when I am testing it, it's working well in SQL Management Studio I am getting expected results.

```
select distinct p.id, p.name, m.name
from test001.npd.projects p,
     test001.npd.customer,
     test001.npd.manager w
where lower(p.name) like '%%' and lower(p.customer) like '%%' and lower(m.name) like '%k%'
```

But then I am moving that statement to hibernate `createQuery` method of hibernate, like this:

```java
public List<Projects> findAlike(String projectName, String customerName, String manager) {
    Query q = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select p from projects p, managers m, wine_styles w where 
    lower(p.name) like :name and lower(p.customer) like :customer and lower(m.name) like :manager");
    q.setParameter("name", "%" + projectName.toLowerCase() + "%");
    q.setParameter("customer", "%" + customerName.toLowerCase() + "%");
    q.setParameter("manager", "%" + manager.toLowerCase() + "%");

    List<Projects> lo = (List<Projects>) q.getResultStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    return (List<Projects>) lo;
}
```

And the problem I have is that when I pass `name` and `customer` everything works well, I can search by it but `manager` field each time returns all rows from table.

I am calling that function for each `KeyListener#keyReleased` call like this:

```java
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
 NewProdForm.getData().setProjects(NewProdForm.getData().getProjectService().findAlike(projectInput.getText(), customerInput.getText(), projectManagerInput.getText()));
 NewProdForm.getAppFrame().getProjectListPanel().getTm().fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

Also I am refreshing `tabelModel` each time.
My class implements `KeyListener` and in cosntructor I am adding key listener for each `TextField`

```java
public class Search extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    private JTextField projectInput;
    private JTextField customerInput;
    private JTextField projectManagerInput;
    private JTextField wineStyleInput;
    private JTextField proposedLaunchDateInput;
    private JTextField statusInput;
    public Search() {
        setLayout(null);
        setBackground(Color.white);
        projectInput = new JTextField();
        customerInput = new JTextField();
        projectManagerInput = new JTextField();
        wineStyleInput = new JTextField();
        proposedLaunchDateInput = new JTextField();
        statusInput = new JTextField();

        add(projectInput);
        add(customerInput);
        add(projectManagerInput);
        add(wineStyleInput);
        add(proposedLaunchDateInput);
        add(statusInput);

        projectInput.addKeyListener(this);
        customerInput.addKeyListener(this);
        projectManagerInput.addKeyListener(this);
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do. I search google but all examples which I found shows that I am doing everything correct, but I am sure I am not cause I do not have my results.

**EDIT**
So after some comments suggested I created `procedure` like this

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('npd.searching') IS NOT NULL)
  DROP PROCEDURE npd.searching

USE test001;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE npd.searching
    @project nvarchar(50),
    @customer nvarchar(50),
    @manager nvarchar(50),
    @wine nvarchar(50)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select p.id, p.name, m.name from test001.npd.projects p
        inner join test001.npd.managers m on p.manager_id = m.id
        inner join test001.npd.wine_styles w on p.wine_style_id = w.id
    where 
        lower(p.name) like '%' + @project + '%' and 
        lower(p.customer) like '%' + @customer + '%' and 
        lower(m.name) like '%' + @manager + '%' and 
        lower(w.name) like '%' + @wine + '%';
GO
```

and I tested it in SQL Management Studio like this

```sql
EXEC npd.searching '', '', 'k', '';
```

Everything works like I want. So I also want move it to hibernate so I did something like this

```java
public List<Projects> findAlike(String projectName, String customerName, String manager, String wineStyle) {
        Query q = getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("EXEC npd.searching :name, :customer, :manager, :wine").addEntity(Projects.class);
        q.setParameter("name", "'" + projectName.toLowerCase() + "'");
        q.setParameter("customer", "'" + customerName.toLowerCase() + "'");
        q.setParameter("manager", "'" + manager.toLowerCase() + "'");
        q.setParameter("wine", "'" + wineStyle.toLowerCase() + "'");
        List<Projects> lo = (List<Projects>) q.getResultStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

        return (List<Projects>) lo;
    }
```

but when I call the method I am getting nothing I mean my `arraylist` where I am assigning data from query is empty. What is wrong with that?

**EDIT [SOLVED]**

Ok, after 2h of searching finally found the solution. Solution to problem above, which I use, was `@NamedNativeQueries`. So I added

```java
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
            name = "searchProjects",
            query = "EXEC npd.searching :project, :customer, :manager, :wine",
            resultClass = Projects.class
    )
})
```

and I changed the `findAlike` method to use `@NamedNativeQuery` like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Projects> findAlike(String projectName, String customerName, String manager, String wineStyle) {
    Query query = getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("searchProjects"); // THIS LINE
    query.setParameter("project", projectName.toLowerCase());
    query.setParameter("customer", customerName.toLowerCase());
    query.setParameter("manager", manager.toLowerCase());
    query.setParameter("wine", wineStyle.toLowerCase());
    List<Projects> foundProjects = (List<Projects>) query.getResultStream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());

    return foundProjects;
}
```

Comment: Is `'%k%'` in your SQL query a typo or your want to fetch the results with manager name having `k` in between?

Comment: I want managers with `k` in name

Comment: A couple of issues here. First, it is time to start using ANSI-92 style joins...they have been around for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins Secondly, why not use a stored procedure instead of pass through queries? It is a lot easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for article, very informative. I used old style only because it is simple query and I was not expecting so many issues. About the procedures why not using them it is long story, but I will try both suggestions, to replace that "old style join"

Comment: Why is the wine_styles table even in the query? It isn't referenced at all.

Comment: Start sql profiler and see the real query sent to the sql server

Comment: @SeanLange I copied during I start changes, updated post